# Can I target 10.0.10586 version for UWP project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a new UWP project in VS 2017. It's ok when I'm selecting Anniversary or Cretors Update as target platform version. But I need 10586 as target. In that case I receive the message:

> The project requires a platform SDK (10.0.10586.0) that is not
>   installed. Please visit the following link for more information:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=824810

Mentioned SDK is installed because I have installed VS 2015 too before. In VS 2015 I'm targeting 10.0.10586 with no problems. I've tried to reinstall SDK with no success. 
Is it possible to target 10586 in Vs 2017 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work, does for me. Open the Visual Studio Installer and install the SDK from there.

Comment: Thanks ! Selecting necessary SDKs in VS2017 installer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as mention in previous answer you just need to follow below steps:

This worked for me:

1) Open VS2017

2) CTRL+Q

3) Search 10.0.14393.0

4) Run Installer

ref:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/81727/vs-2017-unable-to-create-template-10-app-error-thi.html